# Dynamically displaying divison from data being fetched from database

Tags: java, javascript, html, css, jsp

I was tring to make a question answer forum in which each question being displayed is having three divisons : Answers Count,View count,Question.So for  achieving this I do something like this :

```
<div id="container">
        <div id="a">
            <p align="center">0</p>
            <p align="center">Answers</p>

        </div>
        <div id="b-wrapper">
            <div id="b">
                <p align="center">0</p>
            <p align="center">Views</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="c-wrapper">
            <div id="c">
                <p align="center">Question</p>
            <p align="right">Asked By Micheal</p>
            </div>
        </div>

     <br style="clear: both;">
</div>
```

In css i did :

```
#container {
            width:  800px;
        }

        #a, #b-wrapper, #c-wrapper {
            float: left;
        }

        #a {
            width: 10%;
            background-color: #0ff;
        }

        #b-wrapper {
            width: 10%;
        }

        #b {
            margin-left: 20px;
            background-color: #0f0;
        }
        #c-wrapper {
            width: 60%;
        }

        #c {
            margin-left: 20px;
            background-color: #EEEEEE;
        }
```

Now I am facing two problems.

1. The divison for Answer is getting a bit bigger in height.How to manage it.
2. I am fetching questions from database Like :

   ```
   while(rs.next){

   String myid=rs.getString("ID");

   //display here all three divisons where rs is ResultSet
   }
   ```

So here problem is that i want to assign this myid to each of the divison And on click of any divison move to second.jsp.

Please help to solve these problems.

Comment: If you want to see it quick ... just putting your 2 into the jsp page. If you want to have slightly better design, consider using a bean. If you want to separate front-end / back-end logic, you could let client get the myids and other data from AJAX call and show them using javascript.

Comment: @MingtaoZhang This is already in a jsp page.I want to know how to assign the ids dynamically to the divisons

Comment: Looks like I misunderstood the question. Which part are you missing if you've known how to dynamically assemble to page?

Comment: OK ... I think you need to write some javascript, by creating a page invocation logic in onclick. Or you could have a <a href=??></a> in the href you could form the url pattern you need.

Comment: @MingtaoZhang I just want that as ResultSet is having many values each with unique Id,I want to assign them to each of dynamically created divisons.and on clicking any divison send them along as url parameter to next page

Comment: What's the obstacle? I think you've got what you need ... in the while loop assign those ids and generate a onclick="pageredirect(<%id%>)", write a javascript function doing pageredirect(pageid)